# My button's text is not resizing?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

My button has following CSS code. When I resize the window the text falls outside of the div in chrome. (usng the mobile layout)

[image]

http://www.syntra-limburg.be/voltijds-praktijkleren

```
a.syntra-green-button {
    background-color: #6faf3c;
    border: 1px solid #9dcc77;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 2%;
    margin: 5px auto 0px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.35em;
    width: 190px;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center; 
    display: block;
}
```

I fixed it using following code but I was wondering if there isn't a more elegant solution? I do not understand why this is happening.

```
.responsive-layout-mobile a.syntra-green-button {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `font-size` percent like `font-size: 115%;`

**css**

```
a.syntra-green-button {
  background-color: #6faf3c;
  border: 1px solid #9dcc77;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 2%;
  margin: 5px auto 0px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 115%;
  width: 190px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set width to auto. You limited it cause of that it overflows

Answer (score 0):

You can change how the width of the button is rendered using the below. First change the width to be percent based for desktop style displays:

```
width: 30%;
```

but also add a minimum width for when it it resized for a responsive device that fits the entire word:

```
min-width: 200px;
```

So full class would be:

```
a.syntra-green-button {
    background-color: #6faf3c;
    border: 1px solid #9dcc77;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 2%;
    margin: 5px auto 0px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.35em;
    width: 200px;
    min-width: 30%;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center; 
    display: block;
}
```

See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8tBQ3/

Answer (score 0):

```
.responsive-layout-mobile a.syntra-green-button {
    font-size: 100%;
}
```